# Smalltalk clone detector

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Does anybody know any clone detection tool for smalltalk source code?

I'm about to try [Nicad3](http://www.txl.ca/nicaddownload.html), but I was wondering if there're tools around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Moose you'll find SmallDude. That is the smalltalk version of [DuDe](http://wettel.github.io/dude.html)